# SharePoint 2013 - Stackoverflow Integration

Tags: 2013, integration

Was wondering if there are connectors that can integrate SharePoint 2013 with Stack overflow. 
or
Do we have to just use the Stack API's to send data to SharePoint 2013

Use Case - A user uploads an attachment to a question in Stackoverflow, the attachment should be stored in SharePoint.

Comment: with the microsoft flow inplace it will interesting to see if some good options are available now